# Add date to release

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, package.json, npm-version

I'd like to display the date of a release on my website (together with the release version e.g. 0.3.1).

**Option 1**

I would prefer to set the date when I bump the version:

`npm version patch` --> preferebly adds a data value to the package.json

**Option 2**

Another approach is to add the date while I build. e.g. `npm run deploy:prod` This approach is in particular applicable and accurate, if the latest dependencies are pulled. Though not for me, since I check in my dependencies to have no surprises when I build in production.

**QUESTION**

How could one add a date to the package.json in both options?

I know how to read:

```
declare function require(moduleName: string): any;
const { version } = require('../../package.json');
    
export const envVersion = {
  VERSION: version
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your query? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49742615/7743705

Comment: @DhruvShah I think that is not Windows safe. (they use export instead of SET. Makes it harder to test). That's why I rather have it in the package.json (like the version too). Thanks though.

Comment: Does your question mean that "is it valid to add a date parameter in package.json"?

Comment: @DhruvShah No. Not valid. I want to simply do it. Preferably with npm version patch.